# Leaflet: how to add click event listener to popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, click, leaflet

i'm using Leaflet library for the first time and i would add a click event listener on popup for every marker.

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  var marker = L.marker([users[i].lat, users[i].lon], {icon: iconOff})
    .on('mouseover', function() { this.setIcon(iconOn); })
    .on('mouseout', function() { this.setIcon(iconOff); })
    .addTo(map);

  var myPopup = L.popup()
    .setContent("<div id='info'><p id='title'>" + users[i].title + "</p><p>" + users[i].addr + "</p></div>");

  marker.bindPopup(myPopup).openPopup();
}
```

I tried to attach a MouseEvent to popup, doing this before binding `myPopup` to marker:

```
myPopup.on('click', function() { alert("Hello"); })
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried to add this following jQuery code (i'm working on Bootstrap and clicking on popup has to show a modal):

```
  $("#info").click(function() {
    $("#userTitle").html(users[i].title).html();
    $("#userAddr").html(users[i].addr).html();
    $("#userDesc").html(users[i].desc).html();

    $("#userDetails").modal("show");
  });
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<?php
  $title = "Map";
  $scriptsH = array('http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js', 'js/showmap.js');
  require_once('header.php');
?>
    <div class="cointainer">
        <div id="map-canvas">
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="userDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="userTitle"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="userDesc"></p>
          <p id="userAddr"></p>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

But it just works on first marker with popup already opened.

Do you know any workaround or just the right way to do that?

Comment: Can we see the exact code?

Comment: i don't think Leaflet Popup supports any events

Comment: @akshay: what do you need?

Comment: I need to see your html code along with the javascript that you have already posted here

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: I edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: any workaround?

Comment: @smartmouse Might be a dirty hack. Add inline `onclick` listener to the popup content (root element).

Comment: How? Can you show what you mean?

Comment: I tried this code: `document.getElementById("info").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("hello");
      });` but its behavior is the same of `$("#info").click()`

Answer (score 2):

Found final workaround! It works:

Here is my updated code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    (function (user) {
        var marker = L.marker([users[i].lat, users[i].lon], {icon: iconOff})
            .on('mouseover', function() { this.setIcon(iconOn); })
            .on('mouseout', function() { this.setIcon(iconOff); })
            .addTo(map);

        var myPopup = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infoWindow');
        myPopup.innerHTML = "<div id='info'><p id='title'>" + users[i].title + "</p><p>" + users[i].addr + "</p></div>";

            marker.bindPopup(myPopup);

        $('#info', myPopup).on('click', function() {
            $("#userTitle").html(users[i].title).html();
            $("#userAddr").html(users[i].addr).html();
            $("#userDesc").html(users[i].desc).html();

            $("#userDetails").modal("show");
        });
    })(users[i]);
}
```

As you can see i create the content of the popup using `L.DomUtil` (DOM element) instead of `L.Popup` (string) for creating content for the popup.
In addition, in my case i added an anonymous function to handle data from JSON.

I got inspired by this [link](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/765#issuecomment-20898234)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to bind the event listener to the elements of the popup.

For example:

```
    var popup = L.popup({offset   : new L.Point(0,-24), 
                         className: 'some-class'})
                             .setLatLng(latlng)
                             .setContent(content)
                             .openOn(map);

    // can access popup._container or popup.contentNode
    $(popup._closeButton).one('click', function(e){
        //do something
    });
```